# Regex - Match between two strings with an exclusion to avoid overlapping

Tags: regex, python-re

I am extracting tables from some Pdf's using Python. Specifically, I am removing tables, which have the potential of overlapping

For a while, the format was the following:

TABLE A:

(stuff that ends with a %)

TABLE B:

(stuff that ends with a %)

etc, etc

I would use this regex to get each of the tables without overlapping (i.e grabbing everything between the first TABLE and the last %):

```
(TABLE [A-Z]:)(([^%]|\n)*)%
```

Recently, the format has changed and now the table ends with a distinct word (Carriage). When I try to add this to my old pattern, it no longer works properly because I was using a negated set (And placing the whole word in here begins negating individual letters). I do not know how to negate the whole string, and every solution I have found I have not been able to successfully integrate into the remainder of the pattern.

P.S I am aware that the Regex module has a findall that permits overlapping, but I am presently restricted to Python standard libraries in my org.

Comment: Do you mean like this? `(?s)(TABLE [A-Z]:)(.*?)\bCarriage\b` https://regex101.com/r/29Q6dO/1 Note that you can write `[^%]|\n` as just `[^%]` because the negated character class also matches a newline.

Comment: Thank you so much! This seems to have done the job.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your pattern, you could write this part `([^%]|\n)*` as `([^%]*)` as the negated character class will also match the newline.

But if you want to use a word instead of a single character that would not work using the negated character class.

What you could do is to make the dot match a newline and match as least as possible chars until you encounter `Carriage`

```
(?s)(TABLE [A-Z]:)(.*?)\bCarriage\b
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/29Q6dO/1)